# How to add filters in ASP.NET Core Web API using Entity Framework

Tags: entity-framework, asp.net-core, asp.net-core-webapi, filtering

I have a simple Web API where I have a list of requests. In the model this requests have a value call "RequestDate"

```
public class Requests
{
    [Key]
    public int IdRequest { get; set; }
    public string RequestType { get; set; } = string.Empty;
    public string PickUpAddress { get; set; } = string.Empty;
    public string DeliveryAddress { get; set; } = string.Empty;
    public string StatusQuote { get; set; } = string.Empty;
    public DateTime RequestDate { get; set; } = new DateTime();
}
```

This is my controller to get the requests data, I have a little implementation to do pagination:

```
[HttpGet("{page}")]
public async Task<ActionResult<List<Requests>>> Get(int page)
{
    var pageResults = 2f;
    var pageCount = Math.Ceiling(_context.Request.Count() / pageResults);

    var requests = await _context.
                            .OrderBy(x => x.RequestDate)
                            .Skip((page - 1) * (int)pageResults)
                            .Take((int)pageResults)
                            .ToListAsync();

    var response = new RequestResponse
            {
                Requests = requests,
                CurrentPage = page,
                Pages = (int)pageCount
            };

    return Ok(response);
}
```

So when I call this API, the endpoint for requests goes something like this:

```
https://localhost:7171/api/Request/1
```

If I want page two then it's like:

```
https://localhost:7171/api/Request/2
```

and so on.

But what I want is to have the possibility to add a filter for the date, this is what my expected result would look like:

```
https://localhost:7171/api/Request?Initialdate=2022/09/06&FinalDate=2022/09/10
```

I saw the following page [Filtering in ASP.NET Core Web API](https://code-maze.com/filtering-aspnet-core-webapi/) where he does just what I want, but he doesn't appear to use Entity Framework, besides he put a lot more implementation into the project, so I wonder if EF offers an easier way to accomplish this.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use query string parameters to pass the **Initialdate** and **FinalDate** along with putting a **where** condition in your ef query to filter out the dates like

```
_context.Requests.Where((o => o.RequestDate >= queryParameters.InitialDate &&
                                o.RequestDate  <= queryParameters.FinalDate))
```

Comment: To clarify, I just had to create a new get controller with the following:
public async Task<ActionResult<List<Request>>> GetByDate([FromQuery] DateTime InitialDate, [FromQuery] DateTime FinalDate)


And then add the code that Ali Khan shows but without the "queryParameters." part